# Contents of two CSV files in PHP and merge them into a third file based on a key field

Tags: php, csv, merge

I've searched the web and looked through existing answers, but I can’t find a solution to this one. I want to use PHP to do the following  task. Here are my files:

CSV file 1: *member.csv*

```
member1|john|smith|2009
member2|adam|jones|2007
member3|susie|rose|2002
```

CSV file 2: classes.csv

```
member1|massage|swimming|weights
member2|gym|track|pilates
member3|yoga|running|stretches
```

I want to output a third file called *file3.csv* which merges the two above files together based on the key field which is the member number. The output should be like this:

```
member1|john|smith|2009|massage|swimming|weights
member2|adam|jones|2007|gym|track|pilates
member3|susie|rose|2002|yoga|running|stretches
```

The delimiter is a bar character. I want to do this just using PHP - no other languages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read both files and store data to the array with keys: member1, ...
2. Write a new file lines in loop:

```php
foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value1) {
    $value2 = $secondArray[$key];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This will not always work if your files are too big, you will run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen('file1.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')) !== FALSE) {
        $memberId = $line[0];
        unset($line[0]);
        $data[$memberId] = $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
if (($handle = fopen('file2.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')) !== FALSE) {
        $memberId = $line[0];
        unset($line[0]);
        $data[$memberId] = array_merge($data[$memberId], $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
ksort($data);       // not needed, but puts records in order by member
if (($handle = fopen('file3.csv', 'w')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        fwrite($handle, "$key|" . implode('|', $value) . "\n");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your speedy reply. I get these errors half way through the output: Notice: Undefined index: TV in E:\Domains\t\trixysvinyl.com-1032237089\user\htdocs\merge2.php on line 25

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in E:\Domains\t\trixysvinyl.com-1032237089\user\htdocs\merge2.php on line 25

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in E:\Domains\t\trixysvinyl.com-1032237089\user\htdocs\merge2.php on line 25

Comment: Are there any extraneous characters and/or blank lines at the end of either file?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It is untested.

```
$arr_one = array();
if (($fp = fopen("member.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $arr_one[$data[0]] = $data;
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
$arr_two = array();
if (($fp = fopen("classes.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $arr_two[$data[0]] = $data;
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
$classes_field_count = sizeof(current($arr_two));
$members = array_keys($arr_one);
foreach ($members as $key) {
  if (!isset($arr_two[$key])) {
    $arr_two[$key] = range(0, ($classes_field_count - 1));
  }
  unset($arr_two[$key][0]);
  $result_arr[$key] = array_merge($arr_one[$key], $arr_two[$key]);      
}
if (($fp = fopen("file3.csv", "w")) !== FALSE) {
  foreach ($result_arr as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, '|');
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: still getting undefined indexes... I'm sorry I think I'm getting the errors because I forgot to mention that some members are not present in the classes file, so the code would need to add on blank fields to file3.csv if this is the case.